# Palindrome problem - What am I doing wrong Here?

Tags: python, string, palindrome

Problem statement:
You are given a binary string S and an integer K. In one operation, you can pick any bit and flip it, i.e turn 0 to 1 or 1 to 0. Can you make the string S a palindrome using exactly K operations?

Print YES if this is possible, and NO if it is not.

Input Format
The first line of input contains one integer T, denoting the number of test cases. The description of T test cases follows.
Each test case consists of two lines of input.
The first line of each test case contains two space-separated integers N and K, denoting the length of the binary string and the number of operations to be performed.
The second line contains the binary string S.
Output Format
For each test case, print the answer on a new line — YES if the S can be made a palindrome using exactly K operations, and NO otherwise.

You may print each character of YES and NO in either uppercase or lowercase (for example, yes, yEs, Yes will all be considered identical).

My solution:

```
T = int(input())
for i in range(T):
    N,K = map(int,input().split())
    S = input()
    counter = 0
    for i in range(int(len(S)/2)):
        if S[i] == S[-1-i]:
            continue
        else:
            counter = counter + 1
    if counter == K:
        print("Yes")
    else:
        print("No")
```

But on submission, it shows the wrong answer, and upon custom input, it shows correct output, can someone point out what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be another problem.  Remember that the question is "Can you convert it to a palindrome in K steps", not "Can you convert it to a palindrome in a minimum of K steps".

If you've discovered you can do it in fewer than K steps, you have to figure out if you can do it in K steps.  For even palindromes, you can flip pairs of bits, or just flip the same bit an even number of times.  For odd palindromes, you can just flip the center bit over and over.

Comment: There might be an assumption that you can only flip a given bit once, but even so, there's a lot of options. A string like `'00001'` could be made into a palindrome with any number of distinct flips between 1 and 4 (`'10001'`, `'10101'`, `'11011'`, `'11111'`).

Comment: @Blckknght.  My point is that if the string has odd length, and you can do it in `k`, then you can do it any number of moves bigger than `k`.  If the string has even length, then you can increase by multiples of 2.

Comment: Right. I was not disagreeing with you. I was just pointing out that if you have K < N, you shouldn't need to flip the same bit more than once. Flipping opposite bits is (for the purposes of making a palindrome) equivalent to flipping the same bit twice.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you're using len(S) instead of N

Comment: From the problem description, they should be the same.

Comment: Yes, but maybe in the tests they also have tests that intentionally get this wrong

Answer (score 0):

#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

```
int main(){
    int t,n,k,i,j,c;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        cin>>n>>k;
        char str[n];
        for( i=1;i<=n;i++){
            cin>>str[i];
        }
        str[0]=i;
        str[n-1]=j;
        while(i<=j){
            if(str[i++]!=str[j--]){
                c--;
            }
            
        }
        if(c=k){
            cout<<"YES"<<endl;
        }
        else{
            cout<<"NO"<<endl;
        }
        
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).